Selecting a column in a where statement
I know someone can do this... just not me.  I want to have a select list that will return a "where" statement I can use in my report query.  For example, I have a column in my table called "Condition A" that is either a 1 or 0.  I have another column in my table called "Condition B" that is either a 1 or a 0.  I want a select list called "Options" that will let the user pick their own where statement.  For this example, the options would be:
Where Condition A = 1
Where Condition B = 1
Null
Then in my report query, I could use that returned value so that my query could say:
select *
from mytable
&Options.
Something like that.  I hope I'm being clear.  I've tried several different ways of making it work but to no avail.  Please help!  Thank you!

for plsql, I think the key phrase for your searches is "dynamic sql"
you simply need something like
myQuery := 'select a, b, c from my_table where ';
then assign the return value that comes from your select list, to myQuery
myQuery := :P1_MY_SELECT_ITEM;
then
execute immediate myQuery;

Here is an example. It's a report on the EMP table with a select list that returns different where clauses.
select list page item
Page item P273_WHERE_CLAUSE, type "Select List", values:

report
Interactive report of type "Function Body returning SQL Query". This is needed since the SQL needs to be generated dynamically.
Source:
DECLARE
    l_query varchar2(4000);
    l_where_clause varchar2(4000); 
BEGIN
    -- need default value so report compiles correctly
    l_where_clause := CASE WHEN :P273_WHERE_CLAUSE IS NULL THEN '1 = 0' ELSE :P273_WHERE_CLAUSE END;
    l_query := 
    q'!select
                      EMPNO,
                      ENAME
                   from
                      EMP
                   where 
                      %0!';
    -- log this message in apex_debug 
    apex_debug.info(
       p_message => q'#chuckle debug: query: %0#',
       p0        => apex_string.format(l_query, l_where_clause));
    return(apex_string.format(l_query, l_where_clause));
END;

Set "Page Items to Submit" (for the dynamic action in the next step)
--update

Note the debug message. When this page is run in debug mode, this message will be visible in the debug messages (just search for "chuckle debug") . This allows for faster debug.
I'd suggest getting familiar with the APEX_STRING api - the FORMAT method can greatly simplify your code (as shown in this blog). In the sample code above the %0 is a substitution variable (both in APEX_STRING.FORMAT and APEX_DEBUG.MESSAGE)


dynamic action
Create a dynamic action on change of P273_WHERE_CLAUSE with a refresh action on the interactive report.
security notes
While this works, this has a big security flaw. The where clause is visible in the page html source. A user can manipulate the select list where clause in the DOM and get other results than what the developer intended. If this is for a production environment, the where clause should be stored in a table and the return value of the select list should just be the primary key of the row containing the where clause. Then in the report code, retrieve the where clause for the select list value from the table. That way the actual SQL is never visible to a user.

Thanks for your help.  I get everything except the "%0" in the SQL statement.  And the reason that's important is because I've tried to add a group by statement and it doesn't like that.  My query:
q'!select grade, count(client_app_id) num_applications, from initiatives_db_mv where %0 group by grade!';

The %0 is a substitution variable in the APEX_STRING.FORMAT API. This allows for quickly replacing strings in other strings (in this case, the where clause in variable l_query) without having to mess with concatenation. I have updated the answer a bit. Let me know if it not clear. I'd also suggesting instrumenting the code a bit with debug statements that speed up the debugging of your own code (shown in the updated code)
